# How to convert ASP.NET Core code to access SQL Server to work with local SQLite DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlite, asp.net-core

I've been developing my web application to work with a SQL Server database hosted on Azure. To interface with it, I've been using code similar to the following:

```cs
SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select page_name from Pages where page_name = @page_name", scn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_name", pageName);

try
{
    scn.Open();
    string ret = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    scn.Close();

    return ret;
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    throw er;
}
finally
{
    if (scn != null)
    {
        if (scn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            scn.Close();
        }
        scn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now that I've realized that I can use a local SQLite database, I'm trying to switch over to that, since there is no reason for this application to need a DB server. I've put in this new connection string:

```
Data Source=test2.db;
```

But I get an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ExtendedSocketException: No such device or address
>
> System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(string hostName)
>   SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

It looks like it's still trying to connect to a SQL Server. How can I make it use the local SQLite database that I put in the connection string?

Comment: SqlConnection/SqlCommand are objects specifically for connecting to an SQL Server database [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8). You need to google using SQLite in asp.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, it was way simpler than I thought it would be.

1. Install the NuGet package `System.Data.SQLite`.
2. Replace all of the instances of `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, etc. with their SQLite equivalents (eg. `SQLiteConnection`, `SQLiteCommand`, `SQLiteDataAdapter`).
3. In `Startup.cs`, change `options.UseSqlServer` to `options.UseSqlite`.